# Responsive images to fit in container both vertically and horizontally ? (screenshots of issue)

Tags: html, css, web

I've been working on a website to put my portfolio in for a bit.  I tried to keep a pretty simple design since the website itself is not supposed to be the center of attention, but I would still like it to be responsive so pretty much anyone can access it.

On the homepage, I would like to display four (4) previews of my best 3D renders.
The idea is simple :
-Organized in a 2x2 grid
-Centered in the parent container
-Images resize to fit the parent container

For visual people, here's an album with a concept and 3 screenshots demonstrating my issue : http://imgur.com/a/Hce4o

My issue is that the images resize only when I adjust the window horizontally, and not vertically.  Meaning if the viewer has a wide screen, the bottom two previews will be partially to completely cut out.

As you can see, the images only change when the width of the window is fiddled with, but not the height.  Here's my code.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <table id="bestsamples">
        <tr><td><a href=""><figure><img class="homethumbnail" src="./img/home_thumbnails/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Thumbnail Sample"></img><figcaption>Sample 1</figcaption></figure></a></td>
        <td><a href=""><figure><img class="homethumbnail" src="./img/home_thumbnails/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Thumbnail Sample"></img><figcaption>Sample 2</figcaption></figure></a></td></tr>
        <tr><td><a href=""><figure><img class="homethumbnail" src="./img/home_thumbnails/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Thumbnail Sample"></img><figcaption>Sample 3</figcaption></figure></a></td>
        <td><a href=""><figure><img class="homethumbnail" src="./img/home_thumbnails/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Thumbnail Sample"></img><figcaption>Sample 4</figcaption></figure></a></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    background:#6b6b6b;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:0;
    }
#bestsamples{
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:1em;
    }
#bestsamples a{
    text-decoration:none;
    }
#bestsamples figure{
    margin:1em;
    }
#bestsamples figcaption{
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-2.5em;
    padding-left:16px;
    height:2.5em;
    font-family:'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight:600;
    line-height:2.5em;
    color:#a3a3a3;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    transition:.25s ease;
    }
#bestsamples figure:hover figcaption{
    padding-left:32px;
    transition:.25s ease;
    }
.homethumbnail{
    max-width:100%;
    }
```

I tried using max-height instead as well as setting height/width to auto, to no avail.
Does anyone know how to make it work ?
I would also greatly appreciate if you had a more efficient/cleaner way to organize this other than using a table.

Thank you in advance ! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to take it out of a table which isn't really designed for layout anymore. Tables can be tough to style responsively. So my suggestion is to try something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <figure>
    <img src='http://placekitten.com/g/500/500'>
    <figcaption>Image 1</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src='http://placekitten.com/g/500/500'>
    <figcaption>Image 2</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src='http://placekitten.com/g/500/500'>
    <figcaption>Image 3</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src='http://placekitten.com/g/500/500'>
    <figcaption>Image 4</figcaption>
  </figure>      
</div><!-- end container -->
```

Style something like this:

```
.container {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.container figure {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: 0 0 50px 5%;
}
.container figure:nth-child(1),
.container figure:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.container figure img {
  max-width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

I have a [live example here on codepen](http://codepen.io/richfinelli/pen/uBlgs). Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey richfinelli,

Sweet, that's definitely much cleaner than the way I made it ! That's also a neat way to learn about :nth-child(#), thanks !

Sadly, the bottom two images still get cut out in wide windows, [same as before](http://i.imgur.com/eeTRPfW.jpg). =(

Comment: Okay, so there's two ways you can go about tackling images that fall below the "fold". (1)The first and simplest way is to simply set a *max-width* on the *.container figure* style statement. This will prevent the images from getting wider than 250px wide. This will also prevent the images from becoming taller that 250px wide (since we are dealing with square images here). You can tweak the max-width to best suite your situation. I updated the above code to demonstrate this. (2)The more robust solution is to use a media query that targets larger screens. I'll put the code in an answer below.

Comment: Thank you a lot for taking the time to help me. =)
It's not perfect, but at least the bottom thumbnails are much less cut out than previously.  I'll deal with it for now.
Thank you again ! =)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a media query for large screens is an acceptable option to account for this. Media queries let you apply CSS only when your screen is greater than or less than a certain width. Using all the same code from my previous answer, plus you could do something like...

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 80%; /* make the container larger */
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .container figure {
    width: 22%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: 4%;
  }
  .container figure:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: 4%;
  }
}
```

`min-width` inside the media query means 'apply this css as long as the width of the browser is a minimum of the number provided. So anything greater than or equal to 1200px will get the css, thus, targeting larger screens only.

This will let all the images sit on one row since the extra real-estate is available. I updated the [live example](http://codepen.io/richfinelli/pen/uBlgs) to also reflect this code.

Hope either this solution or the one I suggested in the comments helps you out!

Comment: Hey again,
Thanks for your time.  I'll make sure to keep an eye on that media query feature for when I'm done with the overall design, especially for portrait displays (mobiles).

Comment: I didn't know which of your answer to check as the one that solved my issue so I checked the other one since it contained most of the information that helped me solve my issue.  But I can switch it to this answer if you want.